# Javascript HTTP GET and POST

Tags: javascript, http

When initiating a HTTP GET or POST request:

- Common browsers do not allow Javacript to call cross domain
- So it means that every HTTP request from a given domain the "Host" in the Request header represents the origin host, say foo.com and that it cannot be modified by the client request?
- Furthermore, when a request originated from a subdomain, like bar.foo.com then the "Host" in the request header will be "bar.foo.com"
- And that this holds true when doing Cross-domain HTTP request, i.e. the "Host" will be foo.com or if from subdomain bar.foo.com, and that the receiving end (the other domain) will see the "Host" as these hosts respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything through the HTTP browser sandbox (not just AJAX calls! IFRAMEs have restrictions based on the same conditions, for different things - namely, you can't control the content of an IFRAME on another domain/host/port/proto, just load pages and see the URI of what is loaded. Content in JS is off-limits) is done client-side rather than server-side: your browser will actively refuse to query anything that does not have:

- The same hostname (subdomains count as different hostnames)
- The same port
- The same access method (HTTP or HTTPS)

For AJAX, this leads into a big red "cannot get due to security"-esque error. For some browsers, the request does happen: there is a way to bypass this restriction, using access-control headers. These effectively tell your browser "I'm friendly to *x*", where x is a wildcard list of domains (and where *** means everything).

To figure this one out, browsers will perform the request, and if CORS is not on, will actively fire an exception (`XMLHttpRequest: x is not allowed by y`). The request, however, *has happened*.

The obvious solution is to add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in order to signify that cross-domain queries to this site are okay. However, bear in mind two things:

- Most browsers have it, but some don't (IE8 <.<)
- CORS has some little bugs of its own if the URLs are hardcoded in the script (read up on it!)

You'll therefore want a JSONP fallback for IE. However, keep in mind that **all this is done client-side** and is no guarantee that there aren't any browsers that will actively disregard CORS or the webkit security model. The entire model also relies on client-side `Host` resolution.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "Is this true", then then the answer is no.

- Browsers *do* allow JavaScript to create GET and POST requests cross domain. What they don't allow is javascript to read the response from a cross domain request.
- The 'Host' in the HTTP header represents the host that the request is being sent to, not the website that caused the host. HOST is necessary because servers are often shared and one server may host many separate websites, so they need to know which one is being requested.
- The website that created the website is often (although not always) identified in the 'REFERER' HTTP Header.

Comment: Right. the 'Host' is the target host. I completely forgot while I was asking the question. X_X

Answer (score 0):

A server that supports CORS will inspect the `Origin` header in the request. The value will be as you described, the server that the request orignates from. In it's reply, the server will send a header called `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. If this matches `Origin`, the browser will accept the response. It obviously also require the browser to support CORS.

Wikipedia have a fairly good [explanation of how it works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Answer (score -1):

- The `Host` HTTP request header is always the domain that the request is *going to*.
- If you're initiating an HTTP GET or POST request using the `XMLHTTPRequest` method, then it won't let you *send* the request if the JavaScript code that sends it isn't on the same domain as the URL you're sending a request too - unless the browser supports cross-origin resource sharing.
- If the browser *does* support [cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), then it will send your request to other domains, but with an additional `Origin` header, indicating the site that served the JavaScript making the request. If the server allows the request, it'll respond with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, listing the domains it'll accept requests from.